# Unwanted Margin around menu

Tags: css

I've searched this all day (its 2pm here atm, so quite a bit of searching), there is a roughly 5px margin for a header include. The answers I've seen are usually related to inline blocks automatically adding margins, or using positioning. I've got both margin and padding set to 0, but still got this gap. Here's some code.

```
<style type="text/css">
#header{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    }
#logo{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
 </style>   
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="../img/logo.jpg" width="591" height="124" alt="SunnahSpace"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get any margin around the header when testing your code, are you sure it's not coming from some other element?

Comment: Can you show us a sreenshot or example HTML of this gap? I've just plugged your above markup into a JSFiddle, and there aren't any gaps.

Comment: Is the margin round the whole element, or only on the right and left side?

Comment: the whole element akos, could it be a browser issue, im viewing it in chrome and safari, you can see it here, http://sunnahmatch.com

Comment: @Nathan I will try to figure out the problem. Wait few minutes. OK? :)

Comment: beggars can't be choosers right? Take your time :)

Comment: Akos, maarons had the fix, thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: OK sorry for me being a bit slow. Maybe next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a margin around your `body` element - add `margin: 0` to your `body` element CSS and if you want your header to take all the space.

Comment: oh, spot on, can't believe I missed that! Forgot to readd the body tags, Good eye maarons, and thanks for the quick response :) Can't believe I've wasted a day of my life on this >.<"